# How to refactor code using if condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have code like below,

```
React.useMemo(() => {
    if (isInProgress && data && data.Run) {
        if (data.Run.partial === true) { //how can i rewrite this
            setIsRunPartial(true);
        }
        else {
            setIsRunPartial(false);
        }
    } 

}, [data, isInProgress]);
```

here the data.Run.partial can be undefined true or false. how can rewrite above code to look clean. i have to call setIsRunPartial to true if data.Run.partial is true and false if data.Run.partial is false.

how can rewrite above code. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: and what if it is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `setIsRunPartial(!!data.Run.partial)`

If it is `undefined`, the `!!` boolean cast will make it become False --> `setIsRunpartial(false)` in case of undefined

Other than that, if `true` or other truthy value --> `setIsRunPartial(!!truthy)` -->`setIsRunPartial(true)`

if `false` or other falsy value --> `setIsRunPartial(!!falsy)` -->`setIsRunPartial(false)`

Comment: I would do `setIsRunPartial(data.Run.partial === true);` just incase it is some other truthy value other than `true`

Comment: Usually I would never compare a Boolean to true. If the value is truthy, the `!!` Boolean cast should make it become true. `!!(1000)` --> true

Comment: thanks  but i dont want to set it to false myself when undefined.

Comment: What do you want to do when it is undefined then ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the value, if you have already a boolean type.

```
setIsRunPartial(data.Run.partial);
```

Comment: I would do `setIsRunPartial(data.Run.partial === true);` just incase it is some other truthy value other than `true`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
React.useMemo(() => {
    if (isInProgress && data && data.Run && data.Run.partial) {
        setIsRunPartial(data.Run.partial);
    } 

}, [data, isInProgress]);
```

If you are using babel and open to adding the @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining package, this can even become

```
React.useMemo(() => {
    if (isInProgress && data?.Run?.partial) {
        setIsRunPartial(data.Run.partial);
    } 

}, [data, isInProgress]);
```

Comment: I would do `setIsRunPartial(data.Run.partial === true);` just incase it is some other truthy value other than `true`